# Using function pointer forward declaration as lamba declaration

Tags: c++, c++11

What's the closest I can get to something like this?

```
.h:
    typedef bool (*DoWorkFunc)(uint32_t dParam1, uint32_t dParam2, bool bParam, float fParam1, float fParam2, MyClass& c1, MyClass2& c2);
    void DoWork(DoWorkFunc func);

.cpp:
    bool MyClass::MyFunc(uint32_t val) {
        DoWork(DoWorkFunc { return c2.mVal < c1.mVal + fParam1 + fParam2; } );

        auto f1 = DoWorkFunc { return (bParam ? dParam1 : c1.mVal) < mVal; };
        auto f2 = DoWorkFunc { return ((dParam1 & dParam2) == 0) == bParam; };

        auto f = val < 3 ? f1: f2;
        DoWork(f);
    }
```

This is the closest clean solution I've been able to get, which requires a mostly copy-pasted solution for the lambda forward declaration.

```
.h:
    typedef bool (*DoWorkFunc)(uint32_t dParam1, uint32_t dParam2, bool bParam, float fParam1, float fParam2, MyClass& c1, MyClass2& c2);
    #define DoWorkLambda [](uint32_t dParam1, uint32_t dParam2, bool bParam, float fParam1, float fParam2, MyClass& c1, MyClass2& c2) -> bool
    void DoWork(DoWorkFunc func);

.cpp:
    bool MyClass::MyFunc(uint32_t val) {
        DoWork(DoWorkLambda { return c2.mVal < c1.mVal + fParam1 + fParam2; } );

        auto f1 = DoWorkLambda { return (bParam ? dParam1 : c1.mVal) < mVal; };
        auto f2 = DoWorkLambda { return ((dParam1 & dParam2) == 0) == bParam; };

        auto f = val < 3 ? f1: f2;
        DoWork(f);
    }
```

This works alright for one-off solution, but ends up with a pretty messy header for multiple functions declarations

.h:

```
    typedef bool (*DoWorkFunc1)(uint32_t dParam1, uint32_t dParam2, bool bParam, float fParam1, float fParam2, MyClass& c1, MyClass2& c2);
    #define DoWorkLambda1 [](uint32_t dParam1, uint32_t dParam2, bool bParam, float fParam1, float fParam2, MyClass& c1, MyClass2& c2) -> bool
    void DoWork1(DoWorkFunc1 func);

    typedef bool (*DoWorkFunc2)(uint32_t dParam1, uint32_t dParam2, bool bParam, float fParam1, float fParam2, MyClass& c1, MyClass3& c2);
    #define DoWorkLambda2 [](uint32_t dParam1, uint32_t dParam2, bool bParam, float fParam1, float fParam2, MyClass& c1, MyClass3& c2) -> bool
    void DoWork2(DoWorkFunc2 func);

    ...
```

For reference, this is what the code looks like without the preprocessor:

```
.h:
    typedef bool (*DoWorkFunc)(uint32_t dParam1, uint32_t dParam2, bool bParam, float fParam1, float fParam2, MyClass& c1, MyClass2& c2);
    void DoWork(DoWorkFunc func);

.cpp:
    bool MyClass::MyFunc(uint32_t val) {
        DoWork([](uint32_t dParam1, uint32_t dParam2, bool bParam, float fParam1, float fParam2, MyClass& c1, MyClass2& c2) -> bool
            {
                return c2.mVal < c1.mVal + fParam1 + fParam2;
            }
        );

        auto f1 = [](uint32_t dParam1, uint32_t dParam2, bool bParam, float fParam1, float fParam2, MyClass& c1, MyClass2& c2) -> bool
        {
            return (bParam ? dParam1 : c1.mVal) < mVal;
        };
        auto f2 = [](uint32_t dParam1, uint32_t dParam2, bool bParam, float fParam1, float fParam2, MyClass& c1, MyClass2& c2) -> bool
        {
            return ((dParam1 & dParam2) == 0) == bParam;
        };

        auto f = val < 3 ? f1: f2;
        DoWork(f);
    }
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use `std::function`?

Comment: I wouldn't use macros for such a task. The risks that this will conflict in any way with other code is to high compared to the _"benefit"_ you get of having shorter function signatures. In addition I think that the version without macros is easier to read and understand, because you see the parameters the function gets, and of what type they are.

Comment: @RSahu Thank you so much for pointing out std::function to me! I've since found it to be a tremendously useful way to pass lambdas around to other functions

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to assign a lambda function to the equivalent raw function pointer, but ONLY if it does NOT use the scope arguments - i.e. the square brackets in the lambda declaration MUST be empty.

So you should be able to declare the function type. The using syntax is easiest:

```
using DoWorkFnType =bool (uint32_t , uint32_t , bool , float , float , MyClass& , MyClass2& );
void DoWork(DoWorkFnType* fn);

bool MyClass::MyFunc(uint32_t val) {
    DoWorkFnType* f1 = [](uint32_t dParam1, uint32_t dParam2, bool bParam, float fParam1, float fParam2, MyClass& c1, MyClass2& c2) -> bool
    {
        return (bParam ? dParam1 : c1.mVal) < mVal;
    };
    DoWorkFnType* f2 = [](uint32_t dParam1, uint32_t dParam2, bool bParam, float fParam1, float fParam2, MyClass& c1, MyClass2& c2) -> bool
    {
        return ((dParam1 & dParam2) == 0) == bParam;
    };

    auto f = val < 3 ? f1: f2;
    DoWork(f);
}

void DoWork(DoWorkFnType* fn)
{
  bool res= fn(arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4,arg5.arg6,arg7);
}
```

If your lambda uses the local scope then only std::function will work to pass the lambda to a child function.

It is not clear at all from your code what you expect DoWork to do, or how it gathers the 7 argument values needed to call `f`, so I will need to leave it there.

Answer (score 0):

## .h:

```
struct DoWorkParams {
  uint32_t dParam1;
  uint32_t dParam2;
  bool bParam;
  float fParam1;
  float fParam2;
  MyClass& c1;
  MyClass2& c2;
};
typedef bool (*DoWorkFunc)(DoWorkParams);
void DoWork(DoWorkFunc func);
```

## .cpp:

```
bool MyClass::MyFunc(uint32_t val) {
    DoWork([](auto p) { return p.c2.mVal < p.c1.mVal + p.fParam1 + p.fParam2; } );

    auto f1 = [](auto p) { return (p.bParam ? p.dParam1 : p.c1.mVal) < p.mVal; };
    auto f2 = [](auto p) { return ((p.dParam1 & p.dParam2) == 0) == p.bParam; };

    auto f = val < 3 ? f1: f2;
    DoWork(f);
}
```

in [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) you need to change `auto p` to `DoWorkParams p`, but the `auto` feature of lambdas was one of the first [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) features that compilers supported, so it probably works.

If multiple different functions share parameters, you can use inheritance.

```
struct DoWorkBaseParams {
  uint32_t dParam1;
  uint32_t dParam2;
  bool bParam;
  float fParam1;
  float fParam2;
};
struct DoWorkParams1:DoWorkBaseParams {
  MyClass& c1;
  MyClass2& c2;
};
struct DoWorkParams2:DoWorkBaseParams {
  MyClass& c1;
  MyClass3& c3;
};
```

etc